# Need help re-positioning a circle when the canvas size changes

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

So I'm using the function from this tutorial

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/gopherwoord-studios-resizing-html5-games/#disqus_thread

it looks like this -

```
 function resizeGame() {
        var gameArea = document.getElementById('canvas-container');
        var widthToHeight = 11 / 6;
        var newWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var newHeight = window.innerHeight;
        var newWidthToHeight = newWidth / newHeight;

        if (newWidthToHeight > widthToHeight) {
            newWidth = newHeight * widthToHeight;
            gameArea.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
            gameArea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
        } else {
            newHeight = newWidth / widthToHeight;
            gameArea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
            gameArea.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
        }

        gameArea.style.marginTop = (-newHeight / 2) + 'px';
        gameArea.style.marginLeft = (-newWidth / 2) + 'px';

        var gameCanvas = document.getElementById('ctx');
        gameCanvas.width = newWidth;
        gameCanvas.height = newHeight;
        HEIGHT = newHeight;
        WIDTH = newWidth
    }
```

So everything that I use WIDTH and HEIGHT to position on the canvas work fine. But there's other things that I have in my game that just use an x and y and don't change with the canvas.

```
 if(drawBall){
                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, (ball.diameter/2) - 5,0, 2*Math.PI);
                ctx.fillStyle = ball.color;
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.restore();
            }
```

What can I do to my ball.x and ball.y to make it so it correctly changes with the canvas?

Comment: Can we get a snippet or a fiddle to see how it look when it runs?

Comment: I believe ball.x and ball.y are x and y positions or coordinates. Given the window height and width, wouldn't a particular percentage of this, give you any given coordinate?

Comment: So should I use the 11/6 ratio..?

Comment: Also I realized that the size of everything isnt being adjusted.. just the positions

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to ratio's.  Knowing that you can always re position things when the screen re-sizes.

```
var ratio = { x:1, y: 1 };
function start(){
    ratio.x = canvas.width / canvas.clientWidth;
    ratio.y = canvas.height / canvas.clientHeight;
    drawSomething();
}

function drawSomething(){
    context.rect(rectX * ratio.x, rectY * ratio.y, rectWidth * ratio.x, rectHeight * ratio.y);
    /// stroke and all that good stuff 
}

now listen for window change
window.onresize = function(){
    // get new ratio's and draw again
    start();
}
```

With this it shouldn't matter what re-size the user does the canvas will draw at the same relative position and size.